# string array to find and offset values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, offset

I'm trying to delcaire mulitiple variable to be found within a cloumn and then offset a value to the next column. the below code only works with the first variable "a*" but not the others.

How might I go about fixing this?

```
Sub a()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sFind(10) As String

sFind(0) = "a*"
sFind(1) = "b*"
sFind(2) = "c*"
sFind(3) = "d*"
sFind(4) = "e*"
sFind(5) = "f*"
sFind(6) = "g*"
sFind(7) = "h*"
sFind(8) = "i*"
sFind(9) = "j*"

For Each rng In Range("J2", Range("J65536").End(xlUp))
    If Not rng.find(sFind(), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Sample data & expected results would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've got the loop the wrong way round. This should work

```
Sub a()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sFind(10) As String
    Dim i as Long

    sFind(0) = "a*"
    sFind(1) = "b*"
    sFind(2) = "c*"
    sFind(3) = "d*"
    sFind(4) = "e*"
    sFind(5) = "f*"
    sFind(6) = "g*"
    sFind(7) = "h*"
    sFind(8) = "i*"
    sFind(9) = "j*"

    With Range("J2", Range("J65536").End(xlUp))
        For i = LBound(sFind) To UBound(sFind)
            Set rng = .Find(what:=sFind(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify inner code and add a loop like below which will check for all entries.

```
For i = lbound(sFind) to ubound(sFind)
    If Not rng.find(sFind(i), LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: And dispense with the outer loop?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try this it shows an error "object variable or With block variable not set" on the 'If Not' line. What does this mean?